# align unordered list items

Tags: html, css, text-align

I have unordered list:

```
-Item1-
-Item2Item2-
Item3Item3Item
```

Each element has different length.
I want to create list in which all items had the same long background color with text aligned like:

```
-----------------
-----Item1-------
-----------------

-----------------
---Item2Item2----
-----------------

-----------------
-Item3Item3Item3-
-----------------
```

Here --- is colored background. How can I do it?

Comment: padding; 0px 10px; padding:0; margin:0; many combinations. None works. It aligns test but not background part((

Comment: Can you give more details/code than that? StackOverflow is a place for getting help with code, not for getting other people to write code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the display of the `ul` to `inline-block` or `block` and setting the width to `auto` will make the items fit to the widest of the options.

```css
ul {
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
li {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2 Item 2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2 Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3 Item 3 Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4 Item 4 Item 4 Item 4</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2 Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3 Item 3 Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4 Item 4 Item 4 Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5 Item 5 Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6 Item 6 Item 6 Item 6 Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for!!! Thanks.